# Syntax error in rails database query

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite

I have a one to many relationship between two tables (User  name: string group: integer) and Relationship (source: integer, target: integer,value: integer). They are related so that userid=relatioship.source.

I am trying to get some json out of it so I have written:

```
 def self.including_relationships
    User.joins("INNER JOIN relationships ON users.id = relationships.source").select("users.name, users.group, relationships.source, relationships.target, relationships.value").each_with_object(Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = []}) do |a, obj| 

      obj['nodes'] << a.slice('name','group')
      obj['links'] << a.slice('source', 'target', 'value')
```

However I get the error

```
SQLite3::SQLException: near "group": syntax error: SELECT users.name, users.group, relationships.source, relationships.target, relationships.value FROM "users" INNER JOIN relationships ON users.id = relationships.source
```

when I remove users.group and 'group' in the slice, it works fine.

I have checked my database schema which looks as follows:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150603200530) do

  create_table "relationships", force: true do |t|
    t.integer "source"
    t.integer "target"
    t.integer "value"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string  "name"
    t.integer "group"
  end

end
```

The tables are all populated as they should be. I can't figure out what the exact syntax error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Group` is a reserved keyword and you should not use it as your column name. 
Basic misconception is people will think `Group By` collectively as a reserved one. `Group` and `By` are two different reserved keywords. 
Change the column name `group` to something else. It will work.
Or If you want to use reserved keyword, [based on the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html)

> If you want to use a keyword as a name, you need to quote it. There
>   are four ways of quoting keywords in SQLite:
>
> **'keyword'**     A keyword in single quotes is a string literal.
>   **"keyword"**     A keyword in double-quotes is an identifier. 
> **[keyword]**      A
>   keyword enclosed in square brackets is an identifier. This is not
>   standard SQL. This quoting mechanism is used by MS Access and SQL
>   Server and is included in SQLite for compatibility. 
>  **`keyword`**      A
>   keyword enclosed in grave accents (ASCII code 96) is an identifier.
>   This is not standard SQL. This quoting mechanism is used by MySQL and
>   is included in SQLite for compatibility.

Please refer the [list of reserved keywords for sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

`group` is a reserved word.

To use it as a database object use back ticks around it.

Part of your statements shall be modified as below:

```
select("users.name, users.`group`,
```

**Documentation**:

- [Keywords and Reserved Words](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/keywords.html)

  - Most of the reserved words in the table are forbidden by standard SQL
    as column or table names (for example, GROUP)